# Will the Java Garbage Collector stop my POSIX threads created from JNI calls?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, posix

I have a time critical application that needs to send a UDP datagram on a set schedule.  The tolerance for jitter is very low on the receiving side.  Implementing this with a java ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor isn't adequate because when the GC does a "Stop the World" collection my thread pauses while the GC does it's job.

I would like to implement the business logic in Java while implementing the time critical portions with POSIX threads in C++ (Native environment is Linux by the way).  This would allow us to save thousands of lines of code written in Java and also get the pacing we need from the native system calls.

My question is this: If I call a JNI function that creates a separate POSIX thread will that thread be "paused" when the Java GC does a "Stop the World" collection?  Are there any pitfalls that an experienced JNI guru would like to point out with this approach or any alternative approaches one would suggest?

As always, thanks to the awesome stack overflow community!

Comment: How about using a better GC, like the HotSpot [G1 GC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/g1-intro-jsp-135488.html)?

Comment: "my thread pauses while the GC does it's job." is this an assumption or conclusion from measurement? Answers to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085544/garbage-collection-and-threads assert that the "stop the world" period is short for modern GCs.

Comment: That GC uses concurrency to get most of its performance gains.  Unfortunately, the processor where this is running is a single core celeron.  I don't think we'll gain anything from the G1 GC unless we upgrade our processor and because this is a SBC style, high temp device, we're stuck with our little celeron for now.

Comment: If you're so jitter sensitive that you consider implementing the timing section natively then any stw pause is no good. At that point you need to be considering os jitter though, eg that resulting from interrupts.

Comment: My jitter sensitive timing is int he 5 to 10 ms range.  GC can interrupt an entire process for up to 300ms.  Thats too long.  The OS won't lock my program up for 300 ms.

Comment: Depending on the allocation behaviour, heap size and memory available, I'd say you have some chance of getting 5-10 ms pauses. It can't be guaranteed of course.

Comment: @Raedwald The stop the world period has been measured at 150ms to 300ms. As far as modern GC I'm using the latest java 1.6 GC tuned to be concurrent mark sweep and with a few other flags we have determined to be best for our app.

Comment: @Matt allocation is a sticky issue. Remember I'm not the only one that allocates objects in memory.  Objects are also allocated by the different parts of the Java API so I can't FULLY control how many objects are created.

Comment: @Matt, my experiences w/ G1 - it leaks memory.

Comment: @bestsss, IME G1 tuning is not well documented and I've found CMS outperforms it when measuring by STW times (and interestingly ParNew appeared to make the app markedly faster than running under G1). I have tuned a latency sensitive app so that 98-99% of pauses are in the 5-10ms, relied on it being up 24/6 only and being able to avoid a full gc in those 6 days though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't block the posix thread (assuming that the gc doesn't use so much cpu that other system calls would be blocked). I would think that it would block access to the posix thread from the java application but only for a very limited time.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is this: If I call a JNI
>   function that creates a separate POSIX
>   thread will that thread be "paused"
>   when the Java GC does a "Stop the
>   World" collection?

It will have no effect. STW affects java threads that needs to arrive to a safe point. A java thread into native code won't be affected either.